# Sql developer error, invaild character. Creating Youtube database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, youtube, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble running a sql database, I wanted to create a youtube like database. I got this error.

```
CREATE TABLE `Like` (   `video_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `customer_id` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `rating` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',   PRIMARY KEY  (`video_id`,`customer_id`),   KEY `date` (`date`),   KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),   KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),   KEY `rating` (`rating`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"'

*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:

CREATE TABLE `movies` (   `id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `year` int(4) DEFAULT '0',   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  CREATE TABLE `Channel` (   `movie_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `customer_id` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

 CREATE TABLE `qualifying` (   `customer_id` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',   `movie_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

 CREATE TABLE `Like` (   `video_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `customer_id` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `rating` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',   PRIMARY KEY  (`video_id`,`customer_id`),   KEY `date` (`date`),   KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),   KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),   KEY `rating` (`rating`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: don't use `int(1)` etc. use `int` instead.

Comment: Your tags indicate an Oracle database, but the script you posted looks like MySQL. Which is it?

Comment: @sstan Its MySQL I think.

Comment: If you need help, use the Create table dialogs. They'll generate the DDL for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are trying to run a SQL script with MySQL syntax on an Oracle database (you are clearly on an Oracle database because you are getting the `ORA-00911` error).

Either you write your script using Oracle syntax, or change databases and use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

From your *Error message* and *script* it is clear that, You are trying to run `Mysql` table scripts in `Oracle` Database which is why you are getting error.

Here are few changes that you need to make in table scripts to wokr in `Oracle` database

- Replace `back-ticks` with `double quotes(")`
- Replace  `int(N)` datatype with `Number(P)`

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE "like"
  ( 
     "video_id"   Number(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
     "customer_id"Number(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
     "rating"     Number(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
     "date"       DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00', 
     CONSTRAINT video_customers_pk PRIMARY KEY ("video_id", "customer_id")
     KEY "date"("date"),  -- Not sure how to change this in oracle
     KEY video_id("video_id"), 
     KEY customer_id("customer_id"), 
     KEY rating("rating") 
  )
```

**Note :** I am not sure about the equivalent of this  `KEY video_id("video_id")` in `Oracle`